# data return is null in php form after ajax submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to submit a php form through ajax, my jquery code is

```
$("#editContraForm").submit(function editContra (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        dataString = $("#editContraForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./validations/contraAjax.php",
        data: dataString,
        action : "edit",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            console.debug("success : "+data);
        },
        error : function(error){
            console.debug("erro");
        }
        }); 

    });
```

and php code is (contraAjax.php)

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
session_start();
include_once '../connect/connectOpen.php';
$action=isset($_REQUEST['action'])?$_REQUEST['action']:'';

if($action=="edit"){
echo 'good';
}
```

and the call is successfule (as shown in firbug) but console prints 'success: ', means data is null. What is wrong with this code, Kindly help me

Comment: then how should i pass my form data, can you kindly help ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not serialize data, but pass an object.

See jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i changed my data to simple string , data: "testdata", but still getting null.

Comment: Are you sure `action` parameter contains `edit`? What's the PHP script output?

Comment: <form name="editContraForm" id="editContraForm" action="" method="post">

Comment: that action is the path to your script.

Comment: No, I mean `$_REQUEST['action']`. Also, again, what's the PHP script output? Does it print `good` or not?

Comment: No, i can't see "good" any where, but i am expecting to return and print it on firbug console, shouldn't it print "good" after successful ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

use action as a parameter and then access it using **$_POST['action'].**

also try to `var_dump($_POST['action'])`;

Comment: how can i use action as parameter, can you kindly help me?

Answer (score 0):

To add an action parameter just concatenate it into the data string.

```
data: dataString + '&action=edit',
```